# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a div transparent. This code was working in javascirpt but now I converted it to JQuery for learning purpose but I get:

> **Error :** Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addtask").click( function() {
      if ($("#taskinput").style.opacity == "100") {
        $("#taskinput").style.opacity = "0";
      }
      else if ($("#taskinput").style.opacity == "0") {
        $("#taskinput").style.opacity = "100";
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
#taskinput {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addtask">
Click me
</button>

<div id="taskinput">

</div>
```

I am not quite sure what is wrong.

Comment: You are executing DOM methods on jQuery objects

Comment: Well, using DOM *properties* on jQuery objects.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#addtask").click( function() {
      var opacity = $("#taskinput").css("opacity");
      console.log("opacity", opacity);
      if (opacity > 0) {
        $("#taskinput").css("opacity", 0);
      }
      else if (opacity == 0) {
        $("#taskinput").css("opacity", 1);
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
#taskinput {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addtask">
Click me
</button>

<div id="taskinput">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use jQuery methods on your jQuery objects instead of the DOM properties you were using before.

Instead of:

```
$("#taskinput").style.opacity = "0";
```

Use:

```
$("#taskinput").css('opacity', 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing a load of things incorrectly here. Most importantly, you can accomplish what you want with just `$("#taskinput").toggle();`.

What you had gotten wrong was:

- You were trying to apply native JavaScript methods on jQuery objects when you were doing `$("#taskinput").style.opacity`. You can use this as long as you dereference the object since each jQuery object also masquerades as an array. You can do that via `$("#taskinput")[0]` or `$("#taskinput").get(0)`
- The opacity property values range from 0 to 1, not 0 to 100.
- You were comparing numbers and strings.

So again, just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) to do what you wanted to do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addtask").click(function() {
      $("#taskinput").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#taskinput {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addtask">
Click me
</button>

<div id="taskinput">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'opacity' of undefined"

The error message shows since you're trying to call the `style` that is an attribute of DOM object on jQuery object, you could always return DOM object instead using `[0]` like :

```
$("#taskinput")[0].style.opacity = "0";
```

But since you're using jQuery it will be better to use the jQuery method `.css()` instead :

```
$("#taskinput").css("opacity", 0);
```

**NOTE :** `opacity` should be between 0 and 1, 100 isn't a valid value of this property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addtask").click(function() {
    var input = $("#taskinput");
    var opacity = input.css('opacity');

    if (opacity == 1) {
      input.css('opacity', 0);
    } else if (opacity == 0) {
      input.css('opacity', 1);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#taskinput {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addtask">
Click me
</button>
<div id="taskinput"></div>
```

Comment: downvoted because "100" or 100 won't work, opacity defaults to 1

Comment: @inorganik do you think this answer still deserve the downvote ?

Comment: Ok, I undid it :)

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying DOM properties on jQuery objects and opacity goes from 0 to 1, not from 1 to 100

If you just want to show or hide, use .toggle

```
$("#taskinput").toggle();
```

To use opacity, try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addtask").click(function() {
    var opc = $("#taskinput").css("opacity");
    $("#taskinput").css("opacity", opc < 1? 1: 0.5);
  });
});
```

```css
#taskinput {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="addtask">
Click me
</button>

<div id="taskinput">
  Hello
</div>
```